# bin and obj directory can't be ignored. Also can't push

Tags: git

If someone clarify that why ignoring

and sometimes pushing doesn't work for me I would be grateful.

I'm a bit new for git.

**here is the Commit screen**

[image]

**Here is .ignorefile content**

```
*.obj
*.exe
*.pdb
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.cache
*.ilk
*.log
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
[Rr]elease*/
_ReSharper*/
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*
***\bin**
***\obj**
*/bin/*
*/obj/*
```

**Pushing problem, While pushing it get stuck git init bare doesn't solve **

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are using `\b` (you really mean a name starting with the BEL character?), and in `*/bin/` the `*`is probably redundant, would have to check...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you commit a file to a git repo, changing .gitignore doesn't then ignore that file.

If you `git rm` the obj and bin files, and keep your .gitignore file as it is and `git commit` , git will then ignore those files.

Comment: files aren't committed yet, and using `git rm` won't make git ignore files again, so both parts of your post are false...

Comment: It's unclear to me whether the obj files have been previously committed.  *This change* may not yet have been committed, sure, but *a version* may have been committed in the past (I'm unfamiliar with this UI so don't know what the pencil means).  If such files have been committed in the past, having them in .gitignore will mean they are not ignored.

Comment: git rm will remove the files from your working area and stage that removal.  Following it with a git commit will remove the files from your repo.  If you then recreate the files, they *will* be ignored because they're included by the patterns in the .gitignore